# Concatenating date and time fields

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro

I have a table invoices with this fields:

```
invDate -> a date field
invTime -> a time field
```

I need to do querys like

```
SELECT top 10 * from invoices WHERE DATETIME(invDate+invTime) 
BETWEEN DATETIME('2013-12-17 17:58') AND DATETIME()
```

or something like that. I don't know how to concatenate the invDate and invTime to create a datetime field. The only thing that i could do is this horribly thing:

```
DATETIME( YEAR(invDate), MONTH(invDate), DAY(invDate), 17, 52 ) AS MyDatetime
```

Couldn't even get hour and time with hour(invTime) and minute(invTime):

```
DATETIME( YEAR(invDate), MONTH(invDate), DAY(invDate), 
HOUR(invTime), MINUTE(invTime) ) AS MyDatetime
```

I'm doing the querys throught the VFP Odbc Driver via PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You were pretty close.  If the value coming from PHP is not of a date/time, how could VFP interpret it properly.  VFP also has a function CTOT()  (character to time), and expects it in the format of 'yyyy-mm-ddThh:MM:ss??'

```
yyyy = 4 digit year
mm = 1 OR 2 digit month
dd = 1 OR 2 digit day
T -- literally the letter "T"
hh = 1 OR 2 digit hour (but typical is 2 anyhow)
MM = 1 or 2 digit minute (but typical is 2)
ss = 1 or 2 digit for seconds -- not required
?? = "AM" or "PM" if you wanted to explicitly provide that vs 24 hour clock
```

The MM and ss are optional, so if you finished with "T1" would be 1:00:00am

Now, to finish your query.

```
WHERE DATETIME(invDate+invTime) 
BETWEEN DATETIME('2013-12-17 17:58') AND DATETIME()
```

Since this appears to be querying all invoices between a given date/time and NOW (via DateTime()), you don't even need between, you can do

```
WHERE YourTable.Column > CTOT( '2013-12-17T17:58')
```

If you specifically DID have a date/time range to consider, THEN you could do something like

```
WHERE YourTable.Column BETWEEN CTOT( '2013-12-05T10:00') AND CTOT( '2013-12-14T11:58')
```

PROBLEMS WITH your DATE() and TIME() implementations

The problem is Date() is a function to either return current date, or create based on y/m/d provided such as date( 2013, 12, 7 ).  If you are passing a string, use CTOD( 'mm/dd/yyyy' ) such as CTOD( 12, 7, 2013 ).

As for the TIME() function that just expects a number and is of no use for you.  From the OleDbProvider, your best bet is to just create a php function that builds a single string in the CTOT() format I've described and pass to the php function the date and time fields.  Then use that as your "CTOT( functionReturnResult )"

Comment: I need to use BETWEEN because the dates are coming from a form to generate reports. Thank you about the CTOT, it's working. The only thing i can't do at this time is concatenate the date and time into a single datetime field. DATETIME(invDate+invTime) is not working. Because if i try with AND invDate > DATE('2013-12-05') AND invTime > TIME('11:18') AND invDate < DATE('2013-12-07') AND invTime < TIME('12:00') is not working.

Comment: @CarlosGoce, see revision bottom of this answer

Answer (score 1):

To add a `Date`  and a `Time` Field together you will need to convert them both to a same datatype 1st and than just simply add them together something like this....

```
DECLARE @D DATE = '2013-12-17' 
DECLARE @T TIME = '17:58:00'

SELECT CAST(@D AS DATETIME) + CAST(@T AS DATETIME)
```

**Result**

```
2013-12-17 17:58:00.000
```

**Your Query**

```
SELECT top 10 * 
from invoices 
WHERE CAST(invDate AS DATETIME) + CAST(invTime AS DATETIME) 
BETWEEN '20131217 17:58:00.000' AND GETDATE()
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to tell that i'm using vfp from PHP with the ODBC driver. Looks like i'm doing something wrong or is not supported if i try with CAST('2013-12-17' AS DateTime) i got "function name is missing". Or CAST(invdate AS DATETIME). That means that CAST didnt exists?